# Assembly - Writing Text In A Certain Location To Display On DOSBox

Tags: string, assembly, text, tasm, dosbox

I am currently working on a game called: "4 In A Row". I am trying to write the instructions of the game to appear on DOSBox when I load the game up. I want to display it in a certain location on the screen but I don't know how to do that.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FphXn.png

I have outlined the code for the instructions.

Thank you very much for anyone who can help me.

The code:

```
inst1 db 'To drop a disc into one of the columns press: 1, 2, 3 or 4.',13,10,'$'

    Instructions1:
        lea dx, [inst1]
        mov dx, offset inst1
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h
```

Comment: I edited my thread. Can you see the image and the code now?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't post the image and the code because I am new to this website, therefore I have less than 10 reputation.

Comment: The code is pure text, just copy-paste it, select it, and click in the button with the curly braces to format it.

Comment: Have you tried `int 10h` function `02h` "Set cursor position"?

Comment: I edited my thread again. Thank you for your help and patience :).

Comment: I am really new to the Assembly language and they teach us very poorly at school about it so I am basically studying it alone from scratch. No I have not Weather Vane. How do I use it?

Comment: @KatomPower that has been answered below!

Comment: "I don't know how to do that" isn't a question. Worse, coming here and asking "How do I print stuff on the screen" demonstrates a lack of research. Where is the screen in memory? Are there any DOS or BIOS functions that allow you to write at an offset?  (I'll give you a hint... you can answer both of these questions in seconds with Google.)

Comment: Why don't you want to accept my answer? Is something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a "gotoxy" **before** displaying the text :

```
inst1 db 'To drop a disc into one of the columns press: 1, 2, 3 or 4.',13,10,'$'

;SET CURSOR POSITION (GOTOXY).
  MOV  DL, 20    ;SCREEN COLUMN.
  MOV  DH, 5     ;SCREEN ROW.
  MOV  AH, 2     ;SERVICE TO SET CURSOR POSITION.
  MOV  BH, 0     ;PAGE NUMBER.
  INT  10H       ;BIOS SCREEN SERVICES.

Instructions1:
    lea dx, [inst1]
    mov dx, offset inst1
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h
```

Comment: Note that `lea dx, [inst1]` is not needed, `dx` is correctly loaded by the following instruction.

Answer (score 2):

I should be cautious about answering on StackOverflow when I cannot check my work.  But from memory...

I believe that you want to look into `Int 10h` using `AH = 2`.  In English, you want to set the cursor position first, before calling 21h to write to STDOUT at that position.

I hope this gets you started down the right path!

Comment: Thank you for your help but I do not know how to use it. Would you be able to show me?

Comment: It looks like Jose beat me to it.  His code is what you're looking for.  Good luck!